# How do I exclude a specific string from being filtered by PHP's sanitize filters?

Tags: php

So what I want to do is print out all the strings in an array, but seperate them with `<p>` tags.

I tried this:

```
echo filter_var( implode( "<p>", $matches[0]), FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS); echo "</p>";
```

but it results in

```
string1</p>string2</p>string3</p>
```

instead of

```
<p>string1</p> <p>string2</p> <p>string3</p>
```

Any thoughts?

EDIT:

if you need the actual full code, here you go:

```
<?php
$file = 'logfile.log';
$searchfor = $_POST['name'];
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
echo "Found matches:\n";
echo filter_var( implode( "<p>", $matches[0]), FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
}
echo "</p>";
else{
   echo "No matches found";
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand it well. What do you need to exclude from the filtering? Also, I don't think that `filter_var( implode( "<p>", $matches[0]), FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS)` can produce the string you have posted (containing `</p>`). And your full code is different. Also, would be good if you post what's inside the `$matches[0]`.

Comment: `'<p>' . implode('</p><p>', $matches[0]) . '</p>'`

Comment: Where is `<p>` in the full code?

Comment: @MarcB , so `echo '<p>' . filter_var( implode( '</p><p>', $matches[0]), FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS) . '</p>' ;` ? That doesn't work, that just prints the html encoded '<' and '>'

Comment: @DawidFerenczy I fixed my code, sorry about that, I copy and pasted from an older version of the file. `$matches[0]` is the array that contains all lines that match search strings from user input (not shown, it's in another file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `htmlspecialchars()` for any arbitrary string that you want to safely display on your page, not `filter_var()`.

Here's the complete solution:

```
foreach ($matches[0] as $str) {
    echo '<p>'.htmlspecialchars($str).'</p>';
}
```

Or, if you really want an (ugly) one-liner:

```
echo implode('', array_map(function ($str) { return '<p>'.htmlspecialchars($str).'</p>'; }, $matches[0]));
```